# javascript select change field price with discount onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

I have an html form with Sub-Total, Discount and Total. The select drop down for Discount has 5%, 10% and 20% values. The select drop down for Sub-Total has $200, $100 and $20 values. Another input text field gets the Total form a calculation on the Sub-Total and Discount.

```
Discount:
<select class="select" name="discount">
  <option value="5" selected>5% discount</option>
  <option value="10">10% discount</option>
  <option value="20">20% discount</option>
</select>

Sub-Total:
<select class="select" name="discount">
  <option value="100" selected>$100</option>
  <option value="200">$200</option>
  <option value="50">$50</option>
</select>

Total:
<input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $db['sellingprice'] ?>">
```

What I need is:

If the input Sub-Total has a value lets say $100 and the Discount to give the Sub-Total is 10% then the Total should change to $90.

Is there any way to update the total price in the input text box every time whenever the Subtotal Price or Discount values are changed?

the calculation to be done is:

> total = subTotal - (subTotal * (discount / 100))

I was able to do something similar with `.onmouseout` but it isn't working quite how I want it to.

```
<script>
var discount = 10; 
document.getElementById("sellingprice").onmouseout = function(){
document.getElementById("price").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("sellingprice").value) * (1.00 - discount)
}
</script>
```

Comment: i don't see any javascript in the question

Comment: Thats why, because I don´t know how to do this

Comment: this is not coders for hire - we help with code you have written - you haven't even tried

Comment: edited with the javascript I am testing but is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nte6xqdv/2/) if you would like to play with it yourself

Using `javascript` and `html` only. This will update the textbox with the value selected `onchange`.

By setting the `onchange` attribute on the select tag, you register the `updateInput()` function as a listener to the `onchange` event.

Then inside the function you can use `document.getElementsByName()` to access the elements and manipulate their values. Notice that `document.getElementsByName()` returns an array-like collection of elements, therefore requiring us to select the first element like so

```
document.getElementsByName("elementNameGoesHere")[0]
```

index of the element we want to select goes here  --------^

```
<select class="select" name="discount" onchange="updateInput()">
  <option value="5" selected>5% discount</option>
  <option value="10">10% discount</option>
  <option value="20">20% discount</option>
</select>

<select class="select" name="cost" onchange="updateInput()">
  <option value="500" selected>$500</option>
  <option value="100">$100</option>
  <option value="20">$20</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="price" value="">

<script>
function updateInput(){
    var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
    var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
}
</script>
```

here is a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nte6xqdv/2/) if you would like to play with it yourself

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2umbkt6f/)

**HTML**

```
Discount:
<select class="select" name="discount" onchange="updateInput()">
   <option value="5" selected>5% discount</option>
   <option value="10">10% discount</option>
    <option value="20">20% discount</option>
</select>

Price:
<input type="text" name="price" value="">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateInput(){
    //get the current amount from the 'discount' field
    var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
    //get the current amount from the 'price' field
    var currentPrice = document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value;
    //new price should be "old price" - "discount%" * "old price"
    document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value =  currentPrice - ((discount/100) * currentPrice);
}
```

Comment: If i change 2 or 3 times the discount keep going down

Comment: If you want to have it only do the calculation on the original number, I would make that clearer in the question. The way you stated it makes it sound like it should be whatever is in the input at the time the select value changes.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    var discount = $(this).val();
    // ensure discount is a number
    discount = parseInt(discount) || 100;

    var price = $("input[name='price']").data("price");
    // ensure price is a number
    price = parseFloat(price) || 0;

    // calculate new price
    price = price * discount / 100;

    // set the price
    $("input[name='price']").val(price.toFixed(2));
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // store initial price
    $("input[name='price']").data("price", $("input[name='price']").val());

    // trigger change on load to have your initial value
    $("select").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: It is working almost fine. It just show me 2 decimals and in my country we dont use decimals example 1.234.00 need to get ride of those .00

Comment: Managed it just changed val(price.toFixed(2)); to val(price.toFixed(0)); and you saved my day thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

Essentially you add an event listener to the select element and run some simple code that works out the discounted price, then update the discounted price input value

http://jsbin.com/yafociqoxe/edit?html,js,output

Javascript:

```
var origPrice = 100;

var discountOption = document.getElementById("discount"),
    discountPrice = document.getElementById("discounted-price");

discountOption.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  discountPrice.value = origPrice - origPrice * this[this.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

Html:

```
<strong>Original Price : $100</strong><br /><br />

  Discount:
<select class="select" id="discount">
  <option value=".05" selected>5% discount</option>
   <option value=".10">10% discount</option>
    <option value=".20">20% discount</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
Dicounted Price:
<input type="text" id="discounted-price" name="price" value="95">
```

Comment: code in questions and answers should be posted here - cant trust an external resource wont disappear

Comment: micahblu how to set the inictial price to <?php echo $db['sellingprice'] ?> ?

Comment: yes you could still use that initial value echoed from that php array variable, assuming its properly set