# html form input javascript sum fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where you  can chose if customer pay taxes or not, if we give discount, default price, price after discount, price after taxes and total price.

Here is what I have:

```
<table width="339" border="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="98">Taxes</td>
        <td width="115">Discount</td>
        <td width="118">Default price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="select" name="taxes">
                <option value="no" selected>no taxes</option>
                <option value="yes">19% taxes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="select" name="discount" onChange="updateInput()">
                <option value="5" selected>5% discount</option>
                <option value="10">10% discount</option>
                <option value="20">20% discount</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="input140" name="cost" id="cost" value="1000">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price after discount</td>
        <td>Taxes</td>
        <td>Total Price to pay</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="price" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="taxes" value="0">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="total" value="0">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function updateInput() {
        var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
        var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
        document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to make this form to work but if I repeat the javascript used it does not work.

Here is the demo Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nte6xqdv/6/

We have the default price 1.000 working fine, if we add discount to customer it changed fine to price after discount

BUT
If I select yes to taxes 19% it does mot change anything and the total price to pay after discount plus taxes is not working neither. Any idea?

Comment: is this your twin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878038/javascript-select-change-field-price-with-discount-onchange

Comment: is the part non working

Comment: No more edits, my answer is now ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost fine, just requires some little fixes : you were using the same name for the select "taxes" and the input "taxes" (now "ttaxes"), you assigned the value "yes" to the tax (I changed it by 19), finally, copy-pasted your own code to calculate discount (used to calculate taxes). Now you have only one thing to do : calculate the sum of both (total price). Here it is, the changes are pointed by commented arrows :

```
<html>
  <body>
<table width="339" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="98">Taxes</td>
    <td width="115">Discount</td>
    <td width="118">Default price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select class="select" name="taxes" onChange="updateInput()">
      <option value="no" selected>no taxes</option>
      <option value="19">19% taxes</option> <!-- <====================== -->
    </select></td>
    <td><select class="select" name="discount" onChange="updateInput()">
      <option value="5" selected>5% discount</option>
      <option value="10">10% discount</option>
      <option value="20">20% discount</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input140" name="cost" id="cost" value="1000"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Price after discount</td>
    <td>Taxes</td>
    <td>Total Price to pay</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="price" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ttaxes" value="0"></td> <!-- <====================== -->
    <td><input type="text" name="total" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateInput(){
    var discount = document.getElementsByName("discount")[0].value;
    var cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = cost - (cost * (discount / 100));

    var taxes = document.getElementsByName("taxes")[0].value; // <======================
    if ( isNaN( taxes ) ) // IF "no taxes" IS SELECTED...
         document.getElementsByName("ttaxes")[0].value = 0;
    else { cost = document.getElementsByName("cost")[0].value;
           document.getElementsByName("ttaxes")[0].value = (cost * (taxes / 100));
         }

    document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value = 
      parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value ) +
      parseFloat( document.getElementsByName("ttaxes")[0].value );
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jose muchas gracias esta funcionando casi perfecto, lo unico que me falta es que el precio final sume precio mas iva mas descuento automaticamente. Me podrias dar una mano con eso porfa?

Comment: @maradoiano, ya casi se lo tengo!

Comment: puse otra pregunta, responde alla para que salga electa la correcta

Comment: maradoiano, edité la respuesta. El cambio está al final de la función "updateInput", todo lo que hace es sumar los dos inputs y desplegar el resultado en el último input. ¡Pruébelo! Con respecto a la otra pregunta, pues resulta que StackOverflow podría anular la otra pregunta porque resulta muy parecida a esta, yo le recomendaría a maradoiano que eliminara la otra pregunta, con el fin de evitar algún tipo de penalización (así son las cosas aquí en StackOverflow). De hecho, ya empezaron a castigar la pregunta con votos negativos.

Comment: El tipo que respondió la otra pregunta lo hizo bien. Acéptela, está buena.

Comment: tengo un drama con un resultado php podrias darme una mirada porfa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900700/php-sum-echo-result-on-the-fly-difficult

Comment: Vamos a echarle una mirada.