# PHP sum echo result on the fly (difficult)

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, search

This is a difficult one but easy for professionals.

I have in mysql the fields: product name, mycost, sellprice and stock. Because I need to know how much I have in investment in my store by each product I created the follow on the fly calculation and is working fine:

```
 <td><?php echo $product['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['stock'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['mycost'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['sellprice'] ?></td>
```

here we calculate on the fly how much is the investment (money) I have in my store according to mycost (the price I payed for the product) * the stock

```
<td><?php echo number_format($product['mycost'] * $product['stock'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
```

It works fine, if mycost for product is 10 and stock is 100 then the result I get on the fly is 1000 in investment

Now because the result (1000) for the product is on the fly (not stored in mysql) I have the follow problem:

The search result show for example 3 different products with 3 different on the fly investment results non stored in mysql. How does can I sum this result and show at the top of the page?

If it was results stored in mysql it was easy but because it is like this:

```
<td><?php echo number_format($product['mycost'] * $product['stock'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
```

I see no way of doing this and that why I am here to ask the professionals

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is the complete code

```
<?php
$cualcategoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_GET['categoria']);
$verproductos = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM `productos`");
while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_assoc($verproductos)) {
?>
<table class="table1000">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:120px;"><div id="rightImage"><img style="border:2px solid #cccccc;" alt="image" src="fotos/<?php echo $mostrar['codigo'] ?>.jpg" width="90" height="90"></div></td>
    <td valign="top" style="width:900px;"><table class="table900">
      <tr>
        <td class="header150">Producto</td>
        <td class="header150">Marca</td>
        <td class="header150">Modelo</td>
        <td class="header150">Cantidad</td>
        <td class="header150">Capital</td>
        <td class="header150">Código</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header150small"><?php echo $mostrar['producto'] ?></td>
        <td class="header150small"><?php echo $mostrar['marca'] ?></td>
        <td class="header150small"><?php echo $mostrar['modelo'] ?></td>
        <td class="header150small"><?php echo number_format($mostrar['stock'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
        <td class="header150small">$ <?php echo number_format($mostrar['costo'] * $mostrar['stock'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
        <td class="header150small"><a class="header150small" href="generar.php?codigo=<?php echo $mostrar['codigo'] ?>"><?php echo $mostrar['codigo'] ?></a></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header150">Precio Costo</td>
        <td class="header150">Precio Neto</td>
        <td class="header150">IVA Incluido</td>
        <td class="header150">Ganancia</td>
        <td class="header150">Ganancia Total</td>
        <td class="header150">Proveedor</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="header150small">$ <?php echo number_format($mostrar['costo'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
        <td class="header150small">$ <?php echo number_format($mostrar['venta'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
        <td class="header150small">$ <?php echo number_format($mostrar['coniva'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
        <td class="header150small">$ <?php echo number_format($mostrar['venta'] - $mostrar['costo'],0,',','.'); ?>
        </td>
        <td class="header150small">$ <?php echo number_format(($mostrar['venta'] - $mostrar['costo']) *  $mostrar['stock'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
        <td class="header150small"><?php echo $mostrar['proveedor'] ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Edited the question, full code. No tengo foreach, probe con los del de la respuesta de mas abajo pero no sirvio de nada. Nesecito sumar los capitales invertidos que van dinamicos en el aire estos <?php echo number_format($mostrar['costo'] * $mostrar['stock'],0,',','.'); ?>

Comment: Need to sum the (capital) <?php echo number_format($mostrar['costo'] * $mostrar['stock'],0,',','.'); ?> but is on the fly

Comment: The meaning my friend is that a beginner to php cannot solve this, other wise I would not be asking here

Comment: Lista mi respuesta. Primero pruébela tal como la puse para que la vea en el navegador, luego le elimina mi array para regresar a la base de datos. Cualquier duda me avisa. Por cierto, se siente bien usar español aquí en StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to use a variable to sum it up on the go (here i'm using totalInvestment as the variable)

```
$totalInvestment = 0;

foreach($products as $product):
    $totalInventsment += product['mycost'] * $product['stock']; ?>

     ...
    <td><?php echo $product['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['stock'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['mycost'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product['sellprice'] ?></td>
    ...

<?php endforeach;
```

Then you can just echo it out like this

```
<?php echo number_format($totalInventsment,',','.'); ?>
```

**EDIT**
If you want it at the top you can add this on the top of your file (will make the site load a little slower n(x)

```
$totalInvestment = 0;
foreach($products as $product){
        $totalInventsment += product['mycost'] * $product['stock'];
}

echo  number_format($totalInventsment,',','.');
```

Comment: This will show the total at the bottom of the page, where the question was for top of page.

Comment: Does I need to add this after while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($showproduct)) { ?

Comment: You only need the part of $totalInvestment = 0; over the while loop.
and the $totalInvestment += under it

Comment: here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nte6xqdv/10/ with the real code I am using and your code inserted. Dreamweaver show error on line

Comment: the error seems to be here $totalInventsment += mostrar['costo'] * $mostrar['stock'];

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'cost'