# How To Show Added Values Of Selected Items?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying display the added values of the checkboxes selected. Here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select style="background-color:#1abc9c;border-color:#1abc9c;">
                    <option value="" selected>How Many People?</option>
                    <option name="people" value="5">5</option>
                    <option name="people" value="10">10</option>
                    <option name="people" value="15">15</option>
                    <option name="people" value="20">20</option>
                    <option name="people" value="25">25</option>
                    <option name="people" value="30">30</option>
                  </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select>
                    <option value="" selected>How Many Candles?</option>
                    <option name="amount" value="100">100</option>
                    <option name="amount" value="150">250</option>
                    <option name="amount" value="500">500</option>
                    <option name="amount" value="1000">1,000</option>
                    <option name="amount" value="1500">1,500</option>
                    <option name="amount" value="2000">2,000</option>
                  </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class=" col-sm-8">
        <span>$0.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change the cost between the span tags, depending on the selected options. I'd like to have a possible outcome each.

1.) People = 5 & Amount = 100 then value equals $3.80
2.)...
3.)...
4.)...
5.)...

Any input will be great?

Comment: show what you have tried so far. add your js

Comment: to start with - the select list should have the name attribute - not the options: <select name="people">"

Comment: Can you elaborate just a bit more if you don't mind? @gavgrif

Comment: I have nothing yet!!! @guradio

Comment: @alexel you should have atleast tried something.note that SO isnt a do my homework for me site. i mean no offence mate but with seeing any effort from you i doubt anyone will help you.

Comment: @alexel try doing it yourself first , as a start use `onchange` on select

Comment: @guradio I am new to coding. And I don't know where to begin with this!!

Comment: @Ramanlfc with onChange, can you provide me just one example?

Comment: @alexel  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878038/javascript-select-change-field-price-with-discount-onchange

Comment: @Ramanlfc Awesom! Thats really all I needed, I just didn't know how to start searching what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did in pure Javascript, but in JQuery would better

Check this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maflorezp/0ayjez4p/)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select onchange="cost()" id="people" style="background-color:#1abc9c;border-color:#1abc9c;">
            <option value="" selected>How Many People?</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select onchange="cost()" id="amount">
            <option value="" selected>How Many Candles?</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="150">250</option>
            <option value="500">500</option>
            <option value="1000">1,000</option>
            <option value="1500">1,500</option>
            <option value="2000">2,000</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class=" col-sm-8">
        <span id="cost">$0.00</span>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="application/javascript">
    function cost() {
        oPeople = document.getElementById('people');
        oAmount = document.getElementById('amount');
        oCost = document.getElementById('cost');

        iPeople = oPeople.options[oPeople.selectedIndex].value;
        iAmount = oAmount.options[oAmount.selectedIndex].value;

        oCost.innerHTML = iPeople * iAmount;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome @rMauricio, this is exactly what I was looking for. Now, to fully understand this, and to help future visitors made by similar individuals, what can this type of programming be called? Plain arithmetic? Math system? Credit based? I don't know where to begin lol

Comment: For me it's only HTML and Javascript, maybe others can comment

Answer (score 0):

```
    Something like this alexel, the name is associated with the select list rather than the options of the select list:

      <select name="amount">
        <option value="" selected>How Many Candles?</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="150">250</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1,000</option>
        <option value="1500">1,500</option>
        <option value="2000">2,000</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just did it